# Get POST data in django form AJAX from

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I'm going to get parameter form AJAX request in Django, Here's what I'm doing:

**base.html:**

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
First name: <input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="register">
</form>
```

**main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").live("click", function(e){
        $.post("/", {
            name: "MY TEXT",
        });
    });
});
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST['name']
    return render_to_response('registration.html', {},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Yes, I know that at this moment my JS doesnt get real data from text form, it sends just a static text "MY TEXT". but when I press button, I get 
**"MultiValueDictKeyError at /
"Key 'name' not found in ""**

What I'm doing wrong?

I've changed my code:
main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").live("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("/", {
           name:'MY TEXT'
        });
    });
});
```

base.html:

```
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    First name: <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register">
</form>
```

**It works**, thanks!

Although, I have two questions:

1. Where am I sending 'MY TEXT' in this case? I ment it returns the ACTUAL data from name field and doesn't return "MY TEXT"
2. The page is still reloading. And I wanted to make it completely AJAX. I mean create a python function to add data from POST request to MySQL database, and return to AJAX-script the result of the operation. And everything without page reload. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that you haven't prevented the browser's default `submit` action from taking place. So your Ajax POST is done, but then immediately the browser itself POSTs - and, as Michal points out, your form doesn't include a `name` field, so the lookup fails.

You need to do two things to fix this. Firstly, use `e.preventDefault();` in your JS click method. Secondly, check for `request.is_ajax()` at the top of your view.

Comment: thank you, I've edited original topic. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Prevent the form from submitting with "e.preventDefault()". Also, it's probably better to bind to the form just in-case the user hits Enter instead of clicking:

base.html

```
<form method="POST" id="register">{% csrf_token %}
First name: <input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#register").live("submit", function(e){
        $.post("/", {
            name: "MY TEXT",
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that you don't have named the text input within html:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: Also, I've edited original topic with two questions. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
$.post("../save_note/", {
        data:'name=MY TEXT'
    });
```

And

```
if 'name' in request.POST:
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a click handler, you could setup a more robust form submit function to do the same thing. Returning false cancels the default submit behavior.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $.post("/", {
        name: "MY TEXT",
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks! It seems to be way more competent code :)