# POST request is not catched by Django server

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, post

I have a Django server running localy at `http://localhost:8000`, with a view set over url `/register/`.

There I have an html file with a form. The view is correctly displayed. But when I push a button, a POST request should be generated, but Django doesn't receive any request.

I don't know if I am setting a wrong host to make the post or I'm having a different trouble, because when testing at jsFiddle from Firefox for windows, I can see the POST with Firebug; but if I use Firefox&Firebug for Ubuntu, at the virtual machine where I'm running Django, no POST request is catched by Firebug.

```
#views.py
def formExample1(request):
    print 'RECEIVED REQUEST: ' + request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        startHour = request.REQUEST['starthour']
        endHour = request.REQUEST['endhour']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.google.es')
    else: #GET
        return render(request, 'formExample1.html')
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', 'helloworld.views.formExample1'),
)
```

And formExample1.html looks like this:

```
<script>
 ...
    // Play button
    $( "#id_playButton" ).click(function() {
        var postdata = {
            'starthour': $("#id_interval").slider("values", 0),
            'endhour': $("#id_interval").slider("values", 1)
        }
        $.post('register/', postdata)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't handle the response at all. You should do it in `.done` part of `.post`

Comment: Probably a silly question, but is `$("#id_playButton")` returning the correct button when you run the page on your dev server?

Comment: do you use firebug? what does the net tab say ?

Comment: @matino how? Please explain at an answer. Teshte, it says nothing at all in the net tab when I push the button (in ubuntu virtual machine, at jsFiddle, Firebug showed the POST with correct variables at Console tab and Net tab)

Comment: So its correctly posting to /register and running your view, but your saying that the most is not being sent?

Comment: @GlynJackson The same url is used for displaying the view (GET request) and to get the data from the user (POST request). If a POST request was correctly generated, Django would redirect the user to google. But that is not happening. I can't see the post with firebug (at ubuntu) and Django is not receiving a post (or I am sending it to a wrong url).

Comment: what happens with request.POST.getlist('return_field[]') ?

Comment: request.POST['starthour'] is blank then?

Comment: @GlynJackson if request.method == 'POST' is never True, because no POST is arriving to Django.

Comment: I see, well I would first reconmed you to install debug toolbar and make sure you have have any redirect etc also it will give you a clear idea what is happening with your POST https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar also if your not point an real form then crsf_token don't exist!

Comment: @GlynJackson I have installed the debug toolbar, and no POST is catched at the Request Vars menu of the debug toolbar (I guess that's where it should appear). I guess the javascript code is wrong, but it does work here: http://jsfiddle.net/787JF/ what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I there are few clear issues with your example, you should read up on [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Here is a quick example using your code...

```
def formExample1(request):
    print 'RECEIVED REQUEST: ' + request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YOURFORM(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              startHour = form.cleaned_data['starthour']
              endHour = form.cleaned_data['endhour']
```

If you want to use the POST values (bad idea) then...

```
def formExample1(request):
    print 'RECEIVED REQUEST: ' + request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
           startHour = request.POST['starthour'] 

    etc
```

However, even this still could be done better, why are you even assigned startHour etc here?

The last issue (if the post data is still not being sent) is a jquery issue. Check out this post: [Get POST data in django form AJAX from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815278/get-post-data-in-django-form-ajax-from)

By the looks of it your are also not posting a real form and therefor missing csrf_token, you need to add this into your script i.e....

```
 csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
```

Or if you want (but there are reasons against this) just add `@csrf_exempt` above your view make it exempt.

Comment: I am not (currently) using a Django form, nor a JQuery form. I have used some JQuery widgets individualy, not together into a form. No validation is being made (currently). That's why I'm getting data from a POST request instead of using Django forms. Your code is just like my first approach, just before I moved to JQuery UI to get nicer widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i make a post using jquery
Things that bother me at your example are the fact that you post at "register/"...i don't use Django (webapp2 instead)..but shouldn't it be "/register" ?

```
var data = {"key":link.id};
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/deleteorders" , //+ link.id
  data: data,
  success: function(data){
    //here you do the processing needed to remove the row from the html;
    $('#'+link.id).parent().remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: It is not working (I haven't used the success parameters with its function, I guess it is not applicable for what I'm doing)